# How to avoid a c++ library from depending on duplicate definitions of protobuf libraries?

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

We have a [cc_library](https://github.com/google/fhir/blob/master/cc/google/fhir/seqex/BUILD#L35) that depend on [our own protos](https://github.com/google/fhir/blob/master/cc/google/fhir/seqex/BUILD#L45) as well as [tensorflow protos](https://github.com/google/fhir/blob/master/cc/google/fhir/seqex/BUILD#L55).

Looking at the build dep, we notice that it's pulling in two definitions of protobuf.

```
% bazel query "deps(//cc/google/fhir/seqex:resource_to_example)" &> resource_to_example_deps
% cat resource_to_example_deps | grep wire
@com_google_protobuf//:src/google/protobuf/wire_format.cc
@com_google_protobuf//:src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite_inl.h
@com_google_protobuf//:src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.h
@com_google_protobuf//:src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc
@com_google_protobuf//:src/google/protobuf/wire_format.h
@protobuf_archive//:src/google/protobuf/wire_format.cc
@protobuf_archive//:src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite_inl.h
@protobuf_archive//:src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.h
@protobuf_archive//:src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc
@protobuf_archive//:src/google/protobuf/wire_format.h
```

It turns out the reason for the above is that:

1. [tensorflow workspace](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c6b8f3617662ff0223eace9774089ce509867160/tensorflow/workspace.bzl) is bring in @protobuf_archieve and @com_google_protobuf
2. tensorflow is using [@protobuf_archieve for proto_gen](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/75adfa5ca180abdd1ccf9408078906e5874c9e2a/tensorflow/core/platform/default/build_config.bzl#L3)
3. Our own cc_proto_library is depending on @com_google_protobuf/, and the default protoc for bazel cc_proto_library is using "@com_google_protobuf//:protoc" as well.

For now, I can avoid this by changing (iii) to use @protobuf_archieve, but I wonder if there is a better way to handle this: for instance, what if the same library needs to depend on protos from a different project that uses a different protoc.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you're hitting https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/5640.

Comment: (I pressed Send too early.) Unfortunately I have no better suggestion than what you found. :(